# How to search/find special characters like &, < or > in the string with regex using Python

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am writing a function in python to search in a text string, with regex, for special charecters.

Once found a match, the program should give error message and exit.

This is what I did so far and able to search for ;,$,%,' but could not search and find characters like &, <, >  in windows.

The current code given below works in windows but not in Linux. But I Want to use this code in windows as well in Linux.

Here is my code:

```
#tests for finding special characters

import sys, re


cmd = input('Enter your command : ')


def chk_cmds(cmd):
    print('chk_cmds: lets look term at %s' % (cmd))
    msg = bool(re.search(r'\;|\$|\%|`', cmd))
    if msg is True:
        print(msg)
        print('Found a suspicious entry in the command : ' + cmd)
        print('Exiting the program')
        return -1
        sys.exit
    else:
        print('Command seems clean ' +cmd)
        return 0
    # return -1

chk_cmds(cmd)
```

Q. How can I also also search for special characters like &, <, > in the strings both in windows and Linux.

I 've tried using backslash escape character for each of those charecters

like  `` bool(re.search(r'\;|\$|\%|`|\&|\<|\>', cmd)) `` but the re.search is not finding them in Windows. (and also current below code seems not working in Linux)

Comment: Can you give an example `cmd` string that is not currently behaving as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Windows machine so I can't test this there but it seems to work on Mac at least.

I used a character list in the regex instead of your method:

```
import sys
import re

def chk_cmds(cmd):
    print('chk_cmds: lets look term at {}'.format(cmd))
    regex = re.compile(r'[&`%;$<>]')
    msg = bool(regex.search(cmd))
    if msg is True:
        print(msg)
        print('Found a suspicious entry in the command : {}'.format(cmd))
        print('Exiting the program')
        return -1
    else:
        print('Command seems clean {}'.format(cmd))
        return 0

mycmd = input('Enter your command : ')

if chk_cmds(mycmd) == -1:
    sys.exit()
```

Your `sys.exit()` command also did nothing since it was after the return, so I've moved it to an if block based on the return code of the function.

Also moved to using `.format` for string formatting although if you are on Python 3.6 or above you should start to use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Answer (score 1):

If you loop through each character of the input string and compare it's ASCII code to a list of ASCII codes which you want it to detect.

```
import sys, re
cmd = input('Enter your command : ')
def chk_cmds(cmd):
    print('chk_cmds: lets look term at %s' % (cmd))
    # ASCII codes for the special characters you specified:
    bad_chars = [36, 37, 38, 59, 60, 62, 63, 96]
    msg = False
    for letter in cmd:
        for i in bad_chars:
            if(ord(letter) == i):
                msg = True
    if msg is True:
        print(msg)
        print('Found a suspicious entry in the command : ' + cmd)
        print('Exiting the program')
        return -1
        sys.exit
    else:
        print('Command seems clean ' +cmd)
        return 0
    # return -1
chk_cmds(cmd)
```

This works for me on Linux using python3

Comment: For the simplicity of the code accepting the first answer by PyPingu,  but I also liked the usage of searching for ASCII charecters suggested by Cole. Thanks both of  you.